# using ebp/esp in conjunction with edi/esi

Tags: c, function, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm working on a project that is implementing functions in assembly and calling them in C.  Doing this requires working with EBP and ESP.  `[EBP + 8]` is pointing to the beginning of a string that I want to reverse in my assembly function.  I was going to do this:

```
cmp     esi, edi
jge     reversed
mov     al, [esi]
mov     bl, [edi]
mov     [esi], bl
mov     [edi], al
inc     esi
dec     edi
jmp     reverse_string
```

I can find the end of the null terminated string just fine if I can use esi and edi pointers.  Do I need to use a different way?  Does everything have to be index offsets?

Comment: As `esi` and `edi` are used as pointers, `jge` should be replaced with `jae`. For example if `esi` is `0x7fffffff` and `edi` is `0x80000000`, the string will not be flipped, because signed number `0x7fffffff` is greater than signed number `0x80000000`. Pointer values should always be treated as unsigned numbers (unless you are doing some special tweaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[EBP + 8]` holds the string pointer you could just move it to `ESI` and proceed from there.

```
mov esi,[ebp+8]
mov edi,esi
mov al,0
mov ecx,-1
cld
repne scasb   ; find the NULL terminator
dec edi
.... your original code follows
```

Comment: Ok well Due to other problems that I had when trying it this way, I thought this wasn't right, but yes